# Can I use IIF in SSRS data sets

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

I have a problem with IIF statements in SSRS. I know and have seen many examples of IIF statements in an expression but i need it to be in the data set and standard IF statements used in normal SQL are not recognised. Basically I want something similar to below:

```
SELECT a,

b,

c,

IF ( D is not NULL, 1, 0)

FROM ...

WHERE ....
```

Its just the `IF ( )` line. Or it could just be a bug with SSRS but can't see anything on any other sites.

Comment: Hi do you want do this in SQL Query or SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you don't specify the type of DBMS in use, `IIF` is not valid SQL syntax. Use `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       CASE D WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` instead ..

```
SELECT a,
    b,
    c,
   CASE WHEN d is not NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END as d
FROM sometable
WHERE ......
```